# Salient pole vs cylindrical rotor

Tags: synchronous, electric-machine

Why is the salient pole rotor in a synchronous machine made of laminated steel whereas a cylindrical rotor does not have any lamination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in stator there is a AC flux and laminated steel construction minimizes the loss due to eddy currents, meanwhile the rotor flux is DC, therfore no eddy currents can exists in rotor.

Comment: I think the OP asked about the rotor i.e. comparison of two types of rotor. I'm not sure if you have addressed that.

Comment: @Andyaka : You are correct, I didn't noticed. Then a logical explanation (my thougts) would be that cylindrical rotors are used in turbo generators with high speeds/forces and they are machined from solid steel. Salient pole rotors are made for hydro plants, slower speeds where laminated construction is cheaper.